# In MVC Migration, I can't update-database from one solution but can do it from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

I created a new ASP.NET web application in VS2017 as blank and installed Entity Framework in it and all important libraries.

Problem is:

1. I successfully ran `Enable-Migrations`
2. I successfully ran `Add-Migration Initialize`
3. But I can't execute `update-database` because I can't connect to SQL Server Express just from this project
4. I tried to open other project and it fork very fine
5. I think there is a problem in the `web.config` file because I start from scratch
6. I add a connection string as follows:

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="DefaultConnection" 
            connectionString="Server=OJ-PC\OJ_SQLEXPRESS;Database=OrdersDb;User Id=sa;Password=******;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
7. I tried a lot of connection strings. I get connection string from SQL Server and add it exactly. I tried same connection string that worked in other project but it didn't work in this project.
8. In two days I tried everything

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The `.` (dot) alias is used when you deal with SQL Server Professional edition.

When it comes to dealing with SQL Express the server name consists of 2 parts separated by backslash `\`.

For instance

```
DESKTOP-3PQ45JH\SQLEXPRESS
```

In this case `DESKTOP-3PQ45JH` is the name of computer, `SQLEXPRESS` is the name of server instance.

Comment: I tried that: (OJ-PC/OJ_SQLEXPRESS) but it didn't work.

Comment: why same connectionstring is working in another project but not working in this project????